# Symfony2 elasticsearch in production returns 500

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

In development everything works. When I switch to production and try to search I simply get 500 error. There are no errors written in logs so I dont understand what can be wrong?

When going to the http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/. I see that the products are saved in index app_dev.

However there is not index related to app. Why is that? Why is it not creating indexes in prod?

config.yml:

```
fos_elastica:
    default_manager: orm
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app:
            index_name: app_%kernel.environment%
            types:
                product:
                    mappings:
                        id:
                            type: integer
                        adminTitle:
                            type: string
                        base:
                            type: double
                        created_at:
                            type: date
                    persistence:
                        # the driver can be orm, mongodb, phpcr or propel
                        # listener and finder are not supported by
                        # propel and should be removed
                        driver: orm
                        model: Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\Product
                        provider: ~
                        listener:
                            immediate: ~
                        finder: ~
                        repository: Mp\ShopBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                            query_builder_method: findProductsBySearch
                            ignore_missing: true
```